# Quickly Calculate Integral of Gamma and Exponentional Distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I know that the Gamma distribution is given by:
$$\frac{1}{\beta^{\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha)}\int x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x/\beta}\,dx.$$
But when I calculate it, I'll always have to use integration by parts to solve it. Which takes so much time. I've seen a quick solution for this example like:
$$\frac{1}{16}\int_{12}^{+\infty} x^2e^{-x/2}\,dx=25e^{-6}\approx 0.062.$$

But I didn't understand how they went from the left side to the right side. Is there a "quick and dirty" solution to solve such integral without having to use integration by parts? Same for Exponentional distribution.

Comment: this site uses [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical formula

Comment: Sorry. My first time here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any positive integer values of $\alpha$ and any real $\beta>0$, by using the third formula of this [LIST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions#Integrals_involving_polynomials), we obtain
$$I=\frac{1}{\beta^{\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_A^{+\infty} x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x/\beta}\,dx
=e^{-A/\beta}\sum_{k=0}^{\alpha-1}\frac{(A/\beta)^k}{k!}.$$
By letting  $\alpha=3$, $\beta=2$, and  $A=12$, we get $I=25e^{-6}$.

Comment: As for Gamma distribution, b stands for lower bounds and a stands for \alpha? What about \beta? In the original question, \alpha was 3 and \beta was 2.

Comment: @Madno Now we have a general formula for any integer $\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Well the gamma function is related to the factorial function, if you already  did not know that. You can check that if you want. Also there is something called a probability distribution function and it supplies standard values for working with the normal distribution function or gamma function as you call it.